# How to use Android MediaStore properly?

Tags: android

Hey I am trying to make Android MediaStore work. This is my code. Permissions are being checked during runtime and are part of the android manifest. Any ideas? I have tried a lot of things so far...

```
      if (!Util.isExternalStorageWritable()) {
            return false;
        }
        ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
        if (resolver == null) {
            return false;
        }
        String videoFileName = "test_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
        ContentValues valuesvideos;
        valuesvideos = new ContentValues();
        //valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + "test Video");
        valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
        valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
        valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
        Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        Uri uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);

  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.amosyuen.videorecorder.demo, PID: 18608
        java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external_primary/video/media
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1611)
            at com.amosyuen.videorecorder.demo.VideoRecorderResultsFragment.galleryAddVideo(VideoRecorderResultsFragment.java:456)
            at com.amosyuen.videorecorder.demo.VideoRecorderResultsFragment.access$200(VideoRecorderResultsFragment.java:97)
            at com.amosyuen.videorecorder.demo.VideoRecorderResultsFragment$2.onItemClick(VideoRecorderResultsFragment.java:160)
            at com.amosyuen.videorecorder.demo.VideoRecorderResultsFragment$VideoFileAdapter$2.onClick(VideoRecorderResultsFragment.java:583)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
            at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: You dont need any permission. Remove the first three lines. Try a different collection.

Comment: I want to save a file to the gallery. Which collection do you propose to use then?

Comment: Just try some different ones. Experiment a bit.

Comment: hmm with other collections e.g. MediaStore.Downloads I am getting a null_ptr exception at OutputStream out = resolver.openOutputStream(uriSavedVideo);

Comment: Start with changing MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY.

Comment: Tried that. E.g. MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL or MediaStore.Downloads(etc..). I am getting in both cases a null pointer exception. Specifically according to the log I am getting:  Error inserting table files has no column named relative_path. Might there be something wrong with the internal sq database?

Comment: `Error inserting table files has no column named relative_path.`. Well indeed. You are not using that. Use `.RELATIVE_PATH` on Andtoid Q. Else `.DATA`.

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 29 (target as well). In this instance I had the relative path option enabled. valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + "test Video");

Comment: ok stupid me..of course it doesnt work when the phone runs on API 27 xD. Now it works. Thanks a lot!